# Better way to handle elements with XPath? Selenium - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am scraping data from a lottery website to store all the past results in a database.

I got a problem that almost all information I want to retrive is at /html/body/div[3]/h2 per page of each date the lottery y drawn, but only one of them is at /html/body/div[2]/h2

To fix it I used the following code.

```
try:

      text = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div\[3\]/h2').text

except :

       text = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div\[2\]/h2').text
```

It works but I don't like it. Is there a better way to handle this kind of discrepancies?

Comment: Looks fine to me. This is what `try/except` blocks are for - see if one thing works, and if it doesn't, try something else.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the *`<h2>`* tag and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *TAG_NAME*:

  ```
  text = self.driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "h2").text
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  text = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h2").text
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  text = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//h2").text
  ```